# Spree admin only accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise

I am trying to setup spree commerce with API and backend only.  I can get the site to start properly and I can login with the admin credentials, but if I click to view my account via the header menu I get the following error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Spree::UsersController):
```

I cant figure out why it is trying to use the `Spree::UsersController` and not the `Spree::Admin::UsersController`

Am I missing something?

**GEMFILE**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'spree_core'
gem 'spree_api'
gem 'spree_backend'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

**ROUTES**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/s/'
  root to: redirect('/')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Your Account" link takes you to your front end account page not the admin account page.  We should probably hide that link if spree_frontend is not in use or direct it to your admin account page instead (feel free to submit a PR to contribute).

If you want to view your users account info go to the users section in the left column of the admin panel and search for them.

Comment: OK no problem, I'll look into playing with Deface and if I can make a clean solution, I'll send a PR!

Comment: I can't seem to find where the content for the Your Account drop down box is being populated.  I've spent a few hours looking and I see the div tag with the data-hook for `admin_login_navigation_bar` in spree/backend/app/views/spree/admin/shared/_header.html.erb, but it is empty.  Where does the content for this get set?